# Making Bootstrap 3 Navbar transparent, with the Theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 in my project and what I wanna do at this point, is make the Bootstrap Navbar transparent. The usual idea would be:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0%;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

I tried this and it didn't work. I then played with the CDNs and discovered that this worked fine... if there was none of that optional theme. This is the [theme](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css).
But unfortunately I insist on the theme. How do I make it transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
opacity: 0.1%;
```

or you can set it according to how much transparency you want to keep.